# I'm Trying to make a blender image sequence. Nothing Shows up and it says "Can't Load"

Tags: texturing

I'm Trying to make a blender image sequence. Nothing Shows up and it says "Can't Load"
Im on blender 4.0 and there are 3 images all pngs labled image01.png image02.png image03.png.
How do I fix this?
[image: Blender Settings and "Can't Load Message]
[image: Blender Version]

Comment: Also I exported these out of photoshop. Smallest Size

Comment: Are you sure the image sequence is where it is supposed to be? The // in front of the image file name says, this is a relative path and the sequence is located in the same folder as the blend file. If you now moved the images or the blend file to a different folder then this relative path does not work anymore.

Comment: Thank you Gordon! That worked!